# Conditional redirect URL java

Tags: javascript

It's realted to Conditional redirect the current URLs to new URLs, so that I can write "ONE script" and copy it into all the current old HTMLs for the same script. It would help those users whom had bookmarked the old URL and redirect to the new URL.

I have an old webpeges like

1. `www.oldsite.com/a1.html`
2. `www.oldsite.com/a1/5698.html`
3. `www.oldsite.com/x1.html`
4. `www.oldsite.com/YY1.html`

and want to get current URL of an user and using location.path and redirect to newsite.com base on the path (suffix)
ie

1. `www.oldsite.com/a1.html`  to `www.newsite.com/b1.html`
2. `www.oldsite.com/a1/5698.html` to `www.newsite.com/b1/5698.html`
3. `www.oldsite.com/x1.html` to `www.newsite.com/99.html`
4. `www.oldsite.com/YY1.html`  to `www.newsite.com/ZZ1.html`

I have tried many times but fail!

Since I am a new comer to HTML, can anyone can help me?
My site held more than a hundred old html!

Here is my draft

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <javascript>
 if window.location.path='/al.html'

  {
 window.location="http://www.newsite.com/b1.html"}

  else if window.location.path='/al/5698.html'

  {
 window.location="http://www.newsite.com/b1/5698.html"}
   .........

 </script>
  </head>
```

Comment: why you use `java` tag in your question ?

Comment: i guess the java script can resolve my question

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
import java.net.URI;

URI oldUri;
```

you can do that translation by creating a new uri from the old.

```
URI newUri = new URI(
    oldUri.getScheme(),
    "www.newsite.com",
    translatePath(oldUri.getPath()),
    oldUri.getQuery(),
    oldUri.getFragment());
```

You haven't provided enough examples for me to know what `translatePath` should do, but given a string like `"/a1.html"` it returns `"/b1.html"`.